# Use of wildcard in application of patch files using 'git am' command

Tags: git, file, patch

On Windows 10, patch files were made and put into a directory using the following:

```
git format-patch SHA1..SHA2 -o <directory_path>\patches
```

Confirmed that files were created. When trying to apply the files that were created using

```
git am <directory_path>\patches\*.patch
```

the following error is returned:

```
fatal: could not open 'directory_path\patches\*.patch' for reading: No such file or directory
```

However, the patches can be applied individually, e.g.

```
git am <directory_path>\patches\0001-filename.patch
```

Also tried using:

```
git am <directory_path>\patches\000[1-3]*.patch
```

But that doesn't work either.  Commands were tested in both Windows Terminal and PowerShell 7.0.3.  What am I missing?

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/1IT785Jf4Zo

Comment: @ElpieKay Thanks for the reference.  Seems amazing that even after 11 years there isn't a more 'built-in' solution.  Thanks again!

Comment: We faced the similar situation in bash shell and used a `for` loop to iterate the patches. You could try a loop in Windows Terminal and Power Shell.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  While I haven’t tried a loop yet, I did try using Git Bash, which is installed with Git for Windows, and it works fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Using `powershell`, the following works for me. In the following, all patch files are in the current directory.

```
git am (dir *.patch).Name
```